# im trying to learn scikit but stucked at the code which is about encoders require their input to be be uniformly string or number

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been learning python form youtube videos. im new to python just a beginner. I saw this code on video so i tried it but getting the error which i dont known how to solve.
This is the following code where im getting trouble. I didint wrote the enitre code as its to long.

````
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
%matplotlib inline


wine = pd.read_csv('wine_quality.csv')
wine.head()
wine.info()
wine.isnull().sum()

#Preprocessing
bins=(2,6.5,8)
group_names=['bad','good']
wine['quality'] = pd.cut(wine['quality'], bins=bins, labels=group_names)
wine['quality'].unique()

label_quality=LabelEncoder()
wine['quality']=label_quality.fit_transform(wine['quality'])
#after this im getting that error

'''TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode, check_unknown)
    112         try:
--> 113             res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
    114         except TypeError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py in _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
     60     if uniques is None:
---> 61         uniques = sorted(set(values))
     62         uniques = np.array(uniques, dtype=values.dtype)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8e211b2c4bf8> in <module>
----> 1 wine['quality'] = label_quality.fit_transform(wine['quality'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    254         """
    255         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 256         self.classes_, y = _encode(y, encode=True)
    257         return y
    258 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode, check_unknown)
    115             types = sorted(t.__qualname__
    116                            for t in set(type(v) for v in values))
--> 117             raise TypeError("Encoders require their input to be uniformly "
    118                             f"strings or numbers. Got {types}")
    119         return res

TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str']'''
```
````

please help me fix my error. it will be great if you will tell me exactly what should i do.

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at your code, but looking at the error it seems that at some stage you are providing a data that is a combination of strings and floats to encoder and it expects a uniform type, one or the other but not both.

Comment: i have edited my question included the code also. please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I checked the Wine Quality dataset, and upon doing:

```
wine['quality'].unique()
```

I got the following output:

```
array([6, 5, 7, 8, 4, 3, 9], dtype=int64)
```

Now since we have values that exceed the upper bound which you have provided in your bins for `pd.cut()` function, the out of limits values will be replaced by NaN values. I checked it on my compiler too, so after performing your preprocessing

```
#Preprocessing
bins=(2,6.5,8)
group_names=['bad','good']
wine['quality'] = pd.cut(wine['quality'], bins=bins, labels=group_names)
wine['quality'].unique()
```

The result I get for `wine['quality'].unique()` is:

```
['bad', 'good', NaN]
Categories (2, object): ['bad' < 'good']
```

This happens because all values that exceed 8 (the upper bound you provided) are changed to NaN, this is mentioned in the documentation for `pd.cut()` function too:

> Out of bounds values will be NA in the resulting Series or Categorical object.
> Therefore I would suggest that you should increase your upper bound in the bins to 9. I tried to do that and the function works fine without any issues.

```
#Preprocessing
bins=(2,6.5,9)
group_names=['bad','good']
wine['quality'] = pd.cut(wine['quality'], bins=bins, labels=group_names)
wine['quality'].unique()
```

And the output for `wine['quality'].unique()` now was:

```
['bad', 'good']
Categories (2, object): ['bad' < 'good']
```

So, we do not have NaN values anymore, and your Label Encoder should now work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and for your time also. Really appreciate it.